# App requests new keychain access to Parse SDK after name change

Tags: xcode, macos, parse-platform, keychain

We recently changed our `bundle name` (*note that it is not the `bundle identifier`).

Ever since then, some users have been reporting that they are getting requests to access the keychain.

I understand that keychain is linked the bundle identifier, but is it also linked to the bundle name?

Or do I have to change some credentials on Parse after a bundle name change?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an item in the keychain needs its Access Control list updating.

Locate the relevant item in the keychain and bring up the context menu (right-click).

[image: Context Menu]

Select `Get Info` and you'll see a dialog with two tabs. Select the second labelled `Access Control`

[image: Access Control Dialog]

As you can see in the above image, the Google Chrome application has access to this item.

Assuming the newly named bundle isn't in the list, you can add it to test. If it is there, remove it to reproduce the problem which your customers are seeing.

Using the [Keychain Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/), you can programmatically retrieve the item's ACL and add / remove your application. You may want to read the [Keychain Services Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) first.

Note, from experience, Apple's Keychain Application doesn't always correctly show what's in each list, but the API does.